# After call to setAnchor(), div element still takes up space (IE only)

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

i have a html of this format.

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<label id='view' onClick="ShowMe()">show my name</label>
<img src="home.jpg" width="800px" height="600px"/>
<div id='name' style="display:none;height:200px">Your Name is DARSHAN</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in javascript i have this function

```
ShowMe()
{
var nameDiv=Ext.get('name');
var viewDiv=Ext.get('view');
nameDiv.setStyle('display','block');
nameDiv.anchorTo(viewDiv,"tr-br?");

}
```

this thing works fine in all browsers but in IE,When i Click on 'Show My name' label,its displays the 'name' tag near the show my name but also a vertical space is taken up by 'name' Div tag and a scroll bar appears. How to get rid of it?

Comment: `this thing works fine in all browsers but in IE`. Talk about luck with those errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing it with one of the experts at office i got to know this.

when you define  Div at one place  and anchorTo somewhere else this problem might come. how the anchor tag works is it will take the coordinates of the div to which we r anchoring and define the top and left of the new tag accordingly. So we need to make sure that we have defined 'poistion' attribute value to 'absolute'.

So to my problem solution was adding

```
<div id='name' style="display:none;height:200px;position:absolute">Your Name is DARSHAN</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

How can this work? There are lots of errors in this code:

There should be a **semicolon** in your style attribute value, not a **comma**:

```
<div id='name' style="display:none;height:200px">
```

There is a typo - `display` is called `dispaly`:

```
nameDiv.setStyle('display','block');
```

Also, what are the setStyle and anchorTo functions? What library are they from? Did you write it yourself? Please provide some more information.

EDIT: Thank you PPvG for adding tag **extjs**

Please provide snippets of the actual working/faulty code *(copy and paste)* instead of manually writing new code.

Comment: Sorry! just wrote the sample program. in the actual code i dont have those errors in the actual code. in the actual program all css are in a separate file! and the actual code snippet is little compicated. so i wrote the abstract here

Comment: Changed the title (pending approval). Hopefully some Ext-JS expert will help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The inline style on  are divided by a ","

That's invalid, CSS rules have to end with a semicolon ";"

IE is pretty picky when it comes to valid html/css